# Unwrapping maintaining distance of vertices

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

Is it possible to unwrap an object while keeping vertices (relative) distance unchanged from the 3D object?

I think that the answer is related to

[Straighten UV Vertices Maintaining Relative Distance](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52745/straighten-uv-vertices-maintaining-relative-distance)

but I can't get from a 3D object.

I have the following object

[image]

performing a cylindrical unwrapping procedure with seams, one gets a uv mapping like this

[image]

in which the (relative) distance of the vertices on the surface of the 3D object is changed by the projection on the uv mapping.

I'd like to keep the distance on the uv mapping proportional to the distance on the object surface.

Thanks!

Comment: Does `UV Unwrap > Unwrap` with method set to either `Angle Based` or `Conformal` achieve what you want?

Comment: @rjg yes it does something similar to what I want, but then I need to warp the texture to fit the UV unwrapping. I know that projections have issues in either maintaining angles, areas and/or distances. So I am a bit confusedm, what would be the best solution if I want to apply a texture to the model I have?